# How do I find out what SubSystem an SDL function belongs to?

Tags: sdl

How do I find out what sub system an SDL function belongs to? On the Wiki they treat all of them as SDL functions, and the code examples don't show initialization of the sub systems at all.

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/APIByCategory. Also, SDL follows logic. Is there any particular function that you not sure of?

Comment: @keltar I'm creating an interface to SDL, and I was having trouble continuously testing whether a function needed a sub system to be loaded or not. I figured there should be a better way. That page should help a lot. Thanks.